# Reset application STATE after JQUERY AJAX Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Is there any way to reset an application STATE after every invoking of JQuery Ajax function?

I am developing a small app: users click on a button to invoke a function. But afterwards, when users want to click other buttons to invoke the same function, the dynamic ID of the first clicked button still persisting, so other buttons cannot be addressed anymore.

Code:

```js
$('#submitComment').on('click', function(){
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        var thiselement = $(this);

        $.ajax({
            url: 'includes/updateicon.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {id:id},
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(data){

                if (data) {

                    $('#submitComment').attr("disabled", true);
                    $('#customComment').val("");
                    $('#updatedicon-'+id).html("DONE").removeClass('badge-danger').addClass('badge badge-success');
                    
                    # CODE HERE TO RESET THE STATE OF THE APP
                } 
                    else {

                    $('#customContent').load("custom/static/error.html");
                    
                    }

            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                $('#customContent').html("There was an Error about getting the Content:" + errorThrown);
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are searching for elements based on ID and IDs need to be unique (this is most likely causing your bug).

A simple fix of this would be:

```
$('.submitComment').on('click', function(){ 
    var id=$(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({data:{id:id}});
})
```

Comment: i've try it before to change it to a Class selector instead of ID (despite that each Button should have its dynamic ID) but it didn't work.. it works only the first time then the ID of the first Button (no matter which of them clicked first) sticks around and prevent the code to assign new ID to other Buttons...

Comment: @1heone have you tried using LET instead of VAR? this may be a scoping issue where VAR may be hoisting and poisoning the variable